# Firebase cloud functions emulator times out after 30000 ms

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run `firebase emulators:starts` on my project that makes use of Cloud Functions.

It starts the local server at port 5001, if I open it in Chrome I get a `{ "status": "alive" }` response, but after 30 seconds it shuts down by itself because of a "timeout".

```
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  Shutting down emulators.
i  Stopping functions emulator

Error: TIMEOUT: Port 5001 was not active within 30000ms
```

The project works fine when deployed to Google Cloud, so what's the issue?

I tried to run it with `sudo` but it didn't help.

I'm on Windows 10 with WSL (Ubuntu).

Comment: What is your goal? Increase the timeout or find the reason of the timeout? If the second, you need to share some code

Comment: The second, but I'm not sure what am I supposed to share, it's just the basic "hello world" example from the docs.

Comment: Oh it makes sense, can u try hard coding a promise resolve on the return? That should work

Comment: Return from what? I get the timeout error even if I don't attempt to call any of the endpoints, if I just let it run for 30 seconds it errors out.

Comment: You should file a report on the firebase-tools GitHub to get in touch with the engineers who built it.  Stack Overflow is not likely to help you here, as there is no evidence that your code is even being executed.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue there https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1458

Comment: I am having this issue when I try to import a large data set. Is there not a extra parameter to extend the timeout session?

Answer (score 13):

As discussed in [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2379#issuecomment-951884721) comment, setting `"host": "127.0.0.1"`in the `firebase.json` resolved the issue for me.

### firebas.json should look sth like this.

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 5000,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"

    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For me [this one](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2379#issuecomment-646854258) worked as well. `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

use the options `--no-localhost` for any `firebase emulator` or `firebase serve`
check this note on `firebase login` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-test-cli
but i checked and this works across all commands if using WSL